# Submission order of input fields

Tags: java, jsp, parameters, struts2, form-submit

I am using Struts2, jspx scenario where I have list of forms on single `.jspx` page with submit button on each form. Each form has few checkboxes whose value is to be captured. To identify which of the form is clicked I have included hidden field on each form with a unique id, and I observed struts helps to set some fields in nested objects of action by giving the java type path as name for checkbox. Like `strutsaction.formlistobject.actualform.selectedServices`. So is there a way where the hidden field setter can be called before setter of checkboxes so it can be identified for which form the checkboxes can be set?

Comment: Can you post a code you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Relying on parameter set order is risky, as it relies on nothing changing in the HTML, S2 code, etc.

You could *try* putting the checkbox interceptor after the params interceptor.

I would almost certainly use a different, simpler approach, either filling a map and transferring, have a form object that has holders for all combinations and choose which one you need based on the hidden field, etc.

(I'd probably also use a submit button value than a hidden field, but that's irrelevant.)